# How can I make this logic a little more rubyesque

Tags: ruby

How could I compact this logic?

```
an_array = some_list.select do |item|                                  
  include_item = true                                                        
  if a_boolean                                                                  
    include_item = a_method?(item)                                     
  end                                                                        
  include_item                                                               
end
```

Comment: This question would be a better fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I urge you to post some more sensible examples; meta-variables lead into the dark side. In your case, In your case, if `a_boolean` is `false`, the code basically evaluates `an_array = some_list.clone`, but in slow motion. Thus, it would be more sensible to write

```
an_array =
  if a_boolean
    some_list.select { |item| a_method?(item) }
  else
    some_list.clone
  end
```

And I still have no clue if it's actually good, because your intention is completely impenetrable by using overgeneric code.

EDIT: Added `.clone`.

EDIT2: As noted in comments, meagar and my meandering brain eventually arrived at the sameish place:

```
an_array = some_list.clone
an_array.select! { |item| a_method?(item) } if a_boolean
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Will consider that next time I post a question.

Comment: Depending on the need to preserve the contents of `some_list`, I'd recomment `some_list.select!(&:a_method) if a_boolean` as the "most" Rubyish.

Comment: @meagar: I thought about it, then rejected it on the grounds of structure sharing, then remembered that I should `.clone`, now your recommendation sounds sensible again. `an_array = some_list.clone; an_array.select!(&:a_method) if a_boolean` works.

Comment: @sawa: Doh, it's not a method, it's a function! That said, I don't understand your syntax...

Comment: meagar, I guess you understand it. Amadan, read the article dated October 3, 2011 on [Andrew Grimm's weblog](http://andrewjgrimm.wordpress.com/).

Comment: I accept this answer and will use the suggestion in the original edit in my code. It's the most readable and it does not clone unnecessarily. Thanks!

Comment: @sawa: Good link. I was missing this: "When you call method(:method_name), you get back an object of class Method that represents the method.". So, `method(:a_method?)` is equivalent to `Kernel.method(:a_method?)` (or whatever the evaluating context is), which returns a `Method` object, which can then get `to_proc`'d. Thanks for teaching me about `method` method. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
an_array = some_list.select{|item| !a_boolean || a_method?(item)}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
an_array = some_list.select { |item| a_boolean ? a_method?(item) : true }
```